# Analytics Google only work in mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I got a issue with google analytics event track.
The onclick event is only wokring in mozilla and internet explorer, i use a class on each buton "ga-track" and on the onclick event i send the ga.push track.
I try switching between universal analytics and but it doesnt work

```
jQuery('.ga-track').on("click", function(){
    var theHREF = jQuery(this).attr('href');      
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'media', 'download', theHREF]);
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Google analytics debugger plugin for chrome is not showing anything.
I uploaded a part, each link hi and low has a track.
http://isawjsc.com/2014/media_center/testing-gallery-isa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the event has enough time to send in Mozilla, but not in WebKit.

Try using hitCallback which will wait until the event is sent before the next page loads:

```
jQuery('.ga-track-isa').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var theHREF = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', function(){
        window.location.href = theHREF;
    }]);

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'media', 'download', theHREF]);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, i change the code for the one that you provide but still not working, and neither mozilla with that code.
Its really weird, i added the link of the page if someone can check.

Comment: Where can I find the my code that you added? Also, can you un-minify your js files?

Comment: its on http://isawjsc.com/2014/wp-content/themes/isa/assets/js/scripts.min.js?ver=d30ea2b24be2ac51b56a3d352f3d344a  on line 286

Comment: Your jQuery selector is `ga-track-isa` not `ga-track`. I updated my code.

Comment: Oh my.... i didnt notice i'll change it.
It worked, like a pro. hitCallBack was an unknow subject for me. Thanks a lot blexy!! i wouldn't fix it if wasn't for you.